# Flutter variables in widgets are not updating after fetching from a API

Tags: api, flutter, http, dart, request

I'm requesting an API and trying to display response value in UI but after assigning newly collected data variable it's not updating the value instead I don't see any changes. Here is my code I'm trying to do

```
Widget buildTop(double height, double width) {
        final Map arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
        String user_id = '';
        var name = '';
        var password = '';
        var phoneno = '';
        var uploadid = '';
        var user_type = '';
        if (arguments != null) {
          user_id = arguments['user_id'];
        }
        print(user_id);
    
        Future fetchData() async {
          AuthService().readStaff("staff", "uploadid", user_id).then((val) {
            print(val);
            setState(() {
              name = val.data[0]['Name'];
              password = val.data[0]['password'];
              phoneno = val.data[0]['phoneno'];
              uploadid = val.data[0]['uploadid'];
              user_type = val.data[0]['user_type'];
            });
            print(name);
          });
        }
    
        fetchData();
        @override
        void initState() {
          fetchData();
          // TODO: implement initState
          super.initState();
        }
    
        print('name $name');
        return Container(
          height: height,
          width: width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: color,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: height * 0.5,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: width * 0.3,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Rank $name',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                          Text(
                            '12',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 140,
                            width: 140,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                image: new NetworkImage(
                                    "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/18/fd/64/18fd644e9cdf81ab785d606584a384fb.jpg"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                          Text(
                            'ID: $uploadid ',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: width * 0.3,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            '',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                          Text(
                            '',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
                          
              Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

I'm calling an API at AuthService().readStaff("staff", "uploadid", user_id) .As I fetch response data variables don't get updated it remains the initial assigned empty string value. How can I update the variable and display it on the page as I receive the API response ??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `Widget buildTop()` method, you should define a `StatefulWidget`.

```
class _Top extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  __TopState createState() => __TopState();
}

class __TopState extends State<_Top> {
  String user_id = '';
  var name = '';
  var password = '';
  var phoneno = '';
  var uploadid = '';
  var user_type = '';

  Future fetchData() async {
    AuthService().readStaff("staff", "uploadid", user_id).then((val) {
      print(val);
      setState(() {
        name = val.data[0]['Name'];
        password = val.data[0]['password'];
        phoneno = val.data[0]['phoneno'];
        uploadid = val.data[0]['uploadid'];
        user_type = val.data[0]['user_type'];
      });
      print(name);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      [...]
    );
  }
}
```